# JavaScript problems with calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little problem... if I run my script in html everything works fine but if I add numbers on the bars that I made and press the equal button nothing happens. I don't know what's the problem

here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
  <head>
    <title>Kalkulaator</title>
    <meta charset="windows-1252">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale1.0">

    <script>

      function calc()
      {
         var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number1').value);
         var number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number2').value);
         var oper = document.getElementById('operaatorid').value;

         if(oper === '+')
         {
              document.getElementById('tulemus').value = number1+number2;
         }


     </script>


     </head>
     <body>

        <input type="text" id="number1"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" id="number2"/><br/><br/>

        <select id="operaatorid">
            <option value=="+">+</option>
        </select>

        <button onclick="calc();">=</button>
        <input type="text" id="tulemus"/>

     </body
 </html>
```

Comment: `<option value=="+">+</option>` extra `=` after `value` and a missing final `}` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your code, as said by [**Alex K.** in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306082/javascript-problems-with-calculator#comment85614374_49306082).

You have two equal symbols (`=`) on your `<option>` and your Javascript function is missing a closing bracket (`}`).

This is the corrected snippet:

```js
function calc() {
  var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number1').value);
  var number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number2').value);
  var oper = document.getElementById('operaatorid').value;

  if (oper === '+') {
    document.getElementById('tulemus').value = number1 + number2;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number1" /><br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="number2" /><br/><br/>

<select id="operaatorid">
    <option value="+">+</option>
</select>

<button onclick="calc();">=</button>
<input type="text" id="tulemus" />
```

Also, in HTML5, you don't need to close input tags, so you can simply have `<input type="text">`.

Comment: do you by any chance know how to add a script that saves the previous calculations that i have done like if i do 4+4=8 and then it has a box where it says the previous calculation was 4+4=8